# Multiple Haml Elements on Same Line

Tags: haml

I want to be able to have two Haml elements on the same line. For example:

`%h1 %a{:href => '/'} Professio.`

That doesn't work. How would I get something like this to work without borking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot put two haml elements on the same line.

You can achieve something similar by using inline html elements:

```
%h1 <a href='/'>Lorem ipsum</a>
```

Why don't you like this format?

```
%h1 
  %a{:href => '/'} Professio.
```

Another option is to write special 'helper' method (that generate an html link).  For example, the link_to in Rails:

```
%h1= link_to 'Professio', root_url
```

Comment: I would like it on the same line because I want the output HTML to be on the same line.

I'll just do multiple lines, thanks.

Comment: Check Garvin answer bellow, he got late but seems to be the right one for this question.

Answer (score 19):

Late answer, but I was just tackling the same problem myself and knew HAML had a way to do this as part of the language.  See the [White Space Removal section of the HAML reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_).

You could do it this way:

```
%h1<
  %a{ :href => '/' } Professio.
```

Or this way:

```
%h1
  %a{ :href => '/' }> Professio.
```

Answer (score 5):

Haml cannot do this. [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) can:

```
h1: a( href='/' ) Professio.
```

is the same as:

```
h1
  a( href="/ ) Professio
```

You can write as deeper tree as you need:

```
ul.nav
  li.active: a( href="/home" ):    strong Home
  li:        a( href="/contact" ): span   Contact
```

[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) also has similar syntax and support this feature, but it's been designed for Node.js environment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Slim, it seems like a nice alternative to HAML!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to preserve the HTML on the same line you could try something like this:

```
irb> print Haml::Engine.new("%h1<\n  %a{:href => '/'} Profession.").render()
<h1><b href='/'>Profession.</a></h1>
```

Found here: [HAML whitespace removal](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)

[Edit: I know that's says b href above...]

Comment: I posted my answer after I realized your answer was essentially the same.  I didn't realize it was the same at first because the code sample is kind of obfuscated.