# How to use the strong tag in haml

Tags: ruby, haml

Yeah so the title pretty much sums it up. How do you do it!?

I write my text as:

```
 lorem ipsum %strong Banana republic bla bla bla
```

wanting to bold the 'Banana republic' part. But the %strong just gets printed out on the screen like it's part of the body text...

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm up to date, but what I know: http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`HAML` utilize indents and line breaks, while reading your code. So you would have to do something like:

```
%p
  lorem ipsum 
  %strong
    Banana republic
  bla bla bla
```

This question is similar: [inline tag in haml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784047/inline-tag-in-haml)

You could use filters to make this more 'ergonomic': http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#filters

Here an example:

```
%p
  :markdown
    lorem ipsum *Banana republic* bla bla bla
```

By default the html filter is applied, so the following would work too:

```
%p
  lorem ipsum <strong>Banana republic</strong> bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 4):

Haml is not convenient in such cases. Something like this should work:

```
lorem ipsum
%strong Banana republic 
bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: http://www.htmltohaml.com/

```
lorem ipsum
%strong Banana republic
bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 1):

If all that you need is a rich text formatting - consider using :markdown or :textile haml filters.

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#markdown-filter

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#textile-filter

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
lorem ipsum
%strong Banana republic
bla bla bla
```